# expected result is not getting

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a data like this:

[image]

And I want this - I am trying with PIVOT but not getting the expected results:

[image]

Query is

```
  SELECT AttendeeID,[Quantity1],[PROD1],[Quantity2],[PROD2],[Quantity3],[PROD3] FROM
  (SELECT * ,
  row_number() over(partition by  AttendeeID order by AttendeeID)rn
  from #ProductTestingwithPosition2) TT
  PIVOT
  (MAX(product) for ProductPosition in ([PROD1],[PROD2],[PROD3])) AS Tab2
  PIVOT
  (sum(Quantity) for QuantityPosition in ([Quantity1],[Quantity2],[Quantity3])) AS Tab3
```

I am getting this output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT AttendeeID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ProductPosition = 'PROD1' THEN product END) as prod1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN QuantityPosition = 'QUANTITY1' THEN quantity END) as quantity1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ProductPosition = 'PROD2' THEN product END) as prod2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN QuantityPosition = 'QUANTITY2' THEN quantity END) as quantity2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ProductPosition = 'PROD3' THEN product END) as prod3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN QuantityPosition = 'QUANTITY3' THEN quantity END) as quantity3
FROM (SELECT ptp.* ,
             row_number() over (partition by  AttendeeID, ProductPosition order by AttendeeID) as seqnum
      FROM #ProductTestingwithPosition2 ptp
     ) ptp
GROUP BY AttendeeID, seqnum;
```

`PIVOT` -- in addition to being non-standard -- is very finicky.  Conditional aggregation is much more powerful and less prone to errors.

Comment: still getting same result

Comment: @Sandeep . . . .Set up a db<>fiddle.  This should be condensing the rows.